# Custom KotlinX Serializer for List class

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, deserialization, kotlinx

I want to make a custom List serializer that will parse invalid json arrays safely. Example: list of Int `[1, "invalid_int", 2]` should be parsed as `[1, 2]`.
I've made a serializer and added it to Json provider, but serialization keeps failing after first element and cannot continue, so I'm getting list of 1 element `[1]`, how can I handle invalid element correctly so decoder will keep parsing other elements?

```
class SafeListSerializerStack<E>(val elementSerializer: KSerializer<E>) : KSerializer<List<E>> {

    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = ListSerializer(elementSerializer).descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: List<E>) {
        val size = value.size
        val composite = encoder.beginCollection(descriptor, size)
        val iterator = value.iterator()
        for (index in 0 until size) {
            composite.encodeSerializableElement(descriptor, index, elementSerializer, iterator.next())
        }
        composite.endStructure(descriptor)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): List<E> {
        val arrayList = arrayListOf<E>()
        try {
            val startIndex = arrayList.size
            val messageBuilder = StringBuilder()
            val compositeDecoder = decoder.beginStructure(descriptor)
            while (true) {
                val index = compositeDecoder.decodeElementIndex(descriptor) // fails here on number 2
                if (index == CompositeDecoder.DECODE_DONE) {
                    break
                }
                try {
                    arrayList.add(index, compositeDecoder.decodeSerializableElement(descriptor, startIndex + index, elementSerializer))
                } catch (exception: Exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace() // falls here when "invalid_int" is parsed, it's ok
                }
            }
            compositeDecoder.endStructure(descriptor)
            if (messageBuilder.isNotBlank()) {
                println(messageBuilder.toString())
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace() // falls here on number 2
        }
        return arrayList
    }
}
```

Error happens after invalid element is parsed and exception is thrown at `compositeDecoder.decodeElementIndex(descriptor)` line with:

```
kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 4: Expected end of the array or comma
JSON input: [1, "invalid_int", 2]
```

I had a feeling that it should "swallow" invalid element and just keep moving, but instead it's stuck and cannot continue parsing, which doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done without custom serializer. Just parse everything as a `String` (specify `isLenient = true` to allow unquoted strings) and then convert to `Int` all valid integers:

```koltin
fun main() {
    val input = "[1, \"invalid_int\", 2]"
    val result: List<Int> = Json { isLenient = true }
        .decodeFromString<List<String>>(input)
        .mapNotNull { it.toIntOrNull() }
    println(result) // [1, 2]
}
```

In a more generic case (when the list is a field and/or its elements are not simple `Int`s), you'll need a custom serializer:

```kotlin
class SafeListSerializerStack<E>(private val elementSerializer: KSerializer<E>) : KSerializer<List<E>> {
    private val listSerializer = ListSerializer(elementSerializer)
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = listSerializer.descriptor

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: List<E>) {
        listSerializer.serialize(encoder, value)
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): List<E> = with(decoder as JsonDecoder) {
        decodeJsonElement().jsonArray.mapNotNull {
            try {
                json.decodeFromJsonElement(elementSerializer, it)
            } catch (e: SerializationException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this solution works only with deserialization from the `Json` format and requires `kotlinx.serialization` 1.2.0+

Comment: May work for primitives, but what about data structures?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way, we can extract json array from decoder given we are using Json to parse it

```
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): List<E> {
        val jsonInput = decoder as? JsonDecoder
            ?: error("Can be deserialized only by JSON")
        val rawJson = jsonInput.decodeJsonElement()
        if (rawJson !is JsonArray) {
            return arrayListOf()
        }

        val jsonArray = rawJson.jsonArray
        val jsonParser = jsonInput.json
        val arrayList = ArrayList<E>(jsonArray.size)

        jsonArray.forEach { jsonElement ->
            val result = readElement(jsonParser, jsonElement)
            when {
                result.isSuccess -> arrayList.add(result.getOrThrow())
                result.isFailure -> Log.d("ERROR", "error parsing array")
            }
        }
        arrayList.trimToSize()
        return arrayList
    }

    private fun readElement(json: Json, jsonElement: JsonElement): Result<E> {
        return try {
            Result.success(json.decodeFromJsonElement(elementSerializer, jsonElement))
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            Result.failure(exception)
        }
    }
```